# https request error in android version < 6.0 after server migration

Tags: android, ssl, https, server-migration

I migrated my server to another host company. All of my apps running android version < 6.0 are now failing to do HTTPS requests, but the problem doesn't apply to newer versions. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7hIe.png) is my error log.

Comment: Did you test your server with ssllabs.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it occured an error in the migration where the machine hosting my services already had a SSL certificate, that certificate wasn't trusted and was running in conflit with mine, causing errors in the older android versions.